# Modify CSS of <select> in Angular UI-grid

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have an angular ui-grid that has a  in the filter section built out like this:

```
, filter: {
           type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
           selectOptions: [
             { value: 'male', label: 'male' },
             { value: 'female', label: 'female' }
            ]
          }
```

That looks ike this:

[image: first image]

I have tried every way I can think of to modify the CSS to make it look like this:

[image: second image]

But no matter what I do, I cant seem to style any aspect of the dropdown... Has anyone had any success trying to style a ui-grid dropdown?

-----EDIT 1-----

[Here is an ultra-simplified pen](http://codepen.io/uxisnow/pen/NdgRrE)

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of `inspect`-ing DOM elements?

Comment: Yes, and thanks for the snide remark. No matter what I change in the DOM, there is no corresponding effect on the options

Comment: It wasn't a remark. It was a question. I asked because, in its current form, your question indicates you are not familiar with it. I cannot inspect pictures of an issue. So please create a [mcve] or, at the very least, provide a link where this issue can be experienced and inpected. I promise I'll help and provide a working solution.

Comment: I apologize if I mistook your comment. Here is a pen
http://codepen.io/uxisnow/pen/NdgRrE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears UI-Grid is not as  customizable as one might think when looking at their front page.

Here is the list of [customizable elements](http://ui-grid.info/customizer/) in UI-Grid and, for the moment, filters are not one of them.

I would have expected a component built on AngularJS to use a directive that would allow complete replacement of the filters template <strike>but it either doesn't exist yet or I wasn't able to find it</strike>.

Edit: After some more digging I found [headerCellTemplate](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef#properties_headercelltemplate) buried deep into their docs. Not entirely sure how one would use it, but I think it holds the key to the treasure chest.

---

The worst part is that the filters they use are built using plain `<select>` and `<option>` tags, which are a real pain to style. A good starting point would be [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5809186/1891677) and the accepted one, from the same question.

As you might notice, copy/pasting the code from the answer I linked works, but it's a pain to implement and maintain.

I must admit I would consider alternatives to UI-Grid in your position, such as [Smart table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) or [ngTable](http://ng-table.com/). I'd also mention Swimlane's [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) for the incredible performances they have achieved (tables moving smoothly with 100k rows - that's something!).

Best of luck!